# SQL JOINS in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two table and need to join them based on email ID. Let me elobrate this with example
[image]

If company name exists after @  in email_id then need to update column 2 with email ID of column 1

[image]

I believe we need to write a substring starting after@ and ending before (.) and doing pattern match but I am not sure how to do that. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: please align your text properly its looking horrible

Comment: Please, use text rather than images. That makes is easier for us to reproduce if we need to.

Comment: Why are you not including the 'us' in 'abcdus'? And what other rules might there be about "exclude these suffixes"? 

All in all, this looks like a terrible problem to try and "solve", and not something you'd want running in production... at most you'd want to do a data conversion to actually pull out the information you need into their own columns, so you can do proper (and efficient) joins.

Comment: As posted this just doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do? You might consider starting here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query

```
 update TableA

 set TableA.Column2= Table2.column1

 From TableA inner join Table2 
 on TableA.column1 like  CONCAT('%', left(RIGHT(Table2.column1,LEN(Table2.column1)-CHARINDEX('@',Table2.column1)),LEN(RIGHT(Table2.column1,LEN(Table2.column1)-CHARINDEX('@',Table2.column1)))-CHARINDEX('.',RIGHT(Table2.column1,LEN(Table2.column1)-CHARINDEX('@',Table2.column1)))) ,'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding the below query will work for requirement.

```
SELECT A.COMPANYNAME, B.MAILID
FROM A 
JOIN B ON A.COMPANYNAME =
  B.SUBSTRING(MAILID, CHARINDEX('@',MAILID) + 1, PATINDEX('%.com%', MAILID) - CHARINDEX('@', MAILID) - 1)
```